# Realtime pathfinding inside a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize paths between origins and destinations using d3. Every time the mouse is clicked it updates the grid/map, and executes `visPath()` function.

I'm using Pathfinding.JS library.

```
var pathLoc = [[],[],[],[]]; // This is a global variable gets updated with the `updateMap` function

function visPath(){

    var grid = new PF.Grid(pathMatrix);
    var finder = new PF.AStarFinder();

    pathData = [];
    if(pathLoc[0].length > 0 && pathLoc[2].length > 0) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            pathLoc[0].forEach(function (d) {
                pathLoc[2].forEach(function (dd) {

                    var gridBackup = grid.clone();
                    var path = finder.findPath(d[0], d[1], dd[0], dd[1], grid);
                    grid = gridBackup;

                    console.log(path);
                    pathData.push(path);

                });
            });

            pathData.forEach(function (d) {

                d.forEach(function (dd) {
                    d3.selectAll("g.rID" + dd[0] + " rect.w" + dd[1]).attr("fill", "#f00");
                });

            })

        }, 2000); //Without the timeout, pathData is always empty. However, with this I only get few paths, not all of them, and not all the time.
    }
}
```

I think that the `pathData` pushes the `path` before `finder.findPath()` finishes finding the path, and I end up with an empty array.

Other functions that could be of help here:

```
// Example of data passed to updateMap() function
// the map could look something like this:
mapData = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1],
    [1,12,13,21,22,1,12,13,21,22,1],
    [1,31,51,51,31,1,33,51,51,32,1],
    [1,21,51,51,42,1,23,51,51,42,1],
    [1,13,41,42,21,1,13,41,42,21,1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2],
    [1,12,13,21,22,1,12,13,21,22,1],
    [1,31,51,51,31,1,31,51,51,31,1],
    [1,21,51,51,42,1,21,51,51,42,1],
    [1,13,41,42,21,1,13,41,43,21,1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1]
]

function updateMap(data){

    pathLoc = [[],[],[],[]];

    //check the type of each cell (residential, commercial...etc.)
    data.forEach(function(d,i){
        d.forEach(function(dd,ii){
            var dString = dd.toString();
            var dNum = +dString.charAt(0);
            var lNum = +dString.charAt(1);

            if(dString.length>1){ // This means it's not a street/road

                // update pathMatrix map, which will be used by Pathfinding 
                pathLoc[dNum-1].push([i,ii]);
                pathMatrix[i][ii] = 0;

                if(dNum==4){ //Recreational
                    // not important now
                }
            }
        })
    });;
}

var pathMatrix = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From your code I don't even see a variable `pathLoc` , how should anyone presume to help you if the code in question is not all here -_-

Comment: I updated the code. `pathLoc` contains an array of arrays of origins and destinations. For now, I'm using `pathLoc[0]` as an array of the origins, each with `[x,y]` value, and `pathLoc[2]` as an array of the destinations, each with `[x,y]` value that corresponds to pathMatrix data.